# Parsing JSON using LINQ

Tags: c#, json.net

My json data are as below.

```
{
   "data":{
      "foo":{
         "sfoo":"1",
         "active":1
      },
      "foo":{
         "sfoo":"2",
         "active":0
      },
      "v":"v1"
   }
}
```

I try to get the value from json with this code:

```
JObject _JObject = JObject.Parse(_JsonString);

var _JItems = _JObject.SelectToken("data[0].foo")
            .Select(s => new
            {
                _Sfoo = (string)s.SelectToken("sfoo"),
                _WhereClause = (string)s.SelectToken("active")
            })
    .Where(w => w._WhereClause == "1");

foreach (var _JItem in _JItems)
{
    MessageBox.Show(_JItem._Sfoo.ToString());
}
```

I am getting an error such as **"Additional information: Value cannot be null."**

Thank you in advance.

Comment: `data` is not an array, and the first `foo` property of the *object* `data` will be overwritten by the second `foo` property. Maybe you meant to make `data` an array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I commented, `data` is an *object* (`{}`) and not an array (`[]`). You're seeing an error because the object `data` has no property `0` defined.

It seems like you'd want your JSON to look something like this instead:

```
{
   "data":{
      "foo":[
         {
            "sfoo":"1",
            "active":1
         },
         {
            "sfoo":"2",
            "active":0
         }
      ],
      "v":"v1"
   }
}
```

Then your parsing code would look like this:

```
var _JItems = _JObject.SelectToken("data.foo")
        .Select(s => new
        {
            _Sfoo = (string)s.SelectToken("sfoo"),
            _WhereClause = (string)s.SelectToken("active")

        })
        .Where(w => w._WhereClause == "1");
```

Comment: Thank you but it seems valid when i check on this url http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com

Comment: @Kerberos there is a difference between syntactically correct and correct based on your intent.

Comment: @Kerberos: As iamkrillin says, your JSON is valid, you're just not accessing it correctly.